# spyder3.0.2(anaconda3)kernel died, restarting on win10 64bit

Tags: python, windows, kernel, anaconda

When I use python3.5 on spyder to run a simple code , I got a big problem.
below is my code

```
import os
import chardet
import pandas as pd
def read():
    print("1")
    try:
        with open("temp.csv", 'rb') as f:
            typ = chardet.detect(f.read())
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("nofile")
        os._exit(0)
    df=pd.read_csv("temp.csv",encoding=typ['encoding'])
    link=df["link"]
    data=[i for i in link]
    return data
read()
```

Then, I got this msg.

> Kernel died, restarting

I try to reinstall anaconda but doesn't work.
I search for this problem on google,but there is no solution.
It's my Dependencies. Can someone help me thanks.

```
jedi >=0.8.1     :  0.9.0 (OK)
matplotlib >=1.0 :  1.5.3 (OK)
nbconvert >=4.0  :  4.2.0 (OK)
numpy >=1.7      :  1.11.2 (OK)
pandas >=0.13.1  :  0.19.1 (OK)
pep8 >=0.6       :  1.7.0 (OK)
pyflakes >=0.6.0 :  1.3.0 (OK)
pygments >=2.0   :  2.1.3 (OK)
pylint >=0.25    :  1.5.4 (OK)
qtconsole >=4.2.0:  4.2.1 (OK)
rope >=0.9.4     :  0.9.4-1 (OK)
sphinx >=0.6.6   :  1.5.1 (OK)
sympy >=0.7.3    :  1.0 (OK)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the problem was? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue , just after starting Spider 3 via Anaconda Navigator ? In Windows 7 64 bit it got worked fine, However, windows 10 64 bit has problem. Any resolution found , please lets all know?